# How can I retrieve properties from this object by PHP?

Tags: php, oop, object

I have an object that responded from Expedia API.

```
[Surcharges] => stdClass Object
(
    [@size] => 1
    [Surcharge] => stdClass Object
        (
            [@type] => TaxAndServiceFee
            [@amount] => 9.59
        )

)
```

How can I retrieve @type và @amount properties.

I tried width `Surcharges->Surcharge->type` or `Surcharges->Surcharge->@type` but do not success

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
Surcharges->Surcharge->{"@type"}
```

Comment: still got `Message:  Undefined property:`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Surcharges->Surcharge->{"@type"}
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake but you solution also fail

Comment: @KiềuDuy  I have updated my answer. Please provide your full code of this section if it fails again.

Comment: James- I disagree. It answers the question directly.